# Calculating $3/10$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I'm trying to calculate $\frac{3}{10}$,working in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$. Is this the correct approach?

Let $x=\frac{3}{10} \iff 10x \equiv 3 \bmod 13 \iff 10x-3=13k  \iff 10x=13k+3$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ $\iff 10x \in \{16,29,42,55,68,81,94,107,120,133,146,159\}$, and the only integer solution to this is $x=9$, therefore $3/10=9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It really does not make sense to use decimals. $22\times10^{-1} = 2.2 $ when calculating in $\mathbb R$ but not in $\mathbb Z_{13}$ since $10^{-1} \in \mathbb Z_{13}$ but $2.2 \not\in \mathbb Z_{13}$. $10^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $10$ in this finite field, and has nothing to do with the multiplicative inverse of $10$ in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Mmmm.  Seasoning.  :-)

Comment: I really don't see how $3 \pmod {13}$ has anything to do with $\{16,19,22,25,\ldots\}$

Comment: @mercio I've edited my working. I can't see where I've gone wrong as the correct answer is 12.

Comment: well I don't know how you got that $9$ since the only multiple of $10$ I see in the new list is $120$... which gives a corresponding $x = 12$. Also the last equivalence is technically wrong.

Comment: @mercio and 120 is the 9th number in the list, so surely $x=9$?

Comment: you have some serious reading problem if you go from "$10x \in \{\ldots\}$" to "$x$ is the index of the first multiple of $10$ in $\{\ldots\}$"

Comment: @mercio Got it! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $10\times 4 = 40 \equiv 1$ mod $13$

Then multiply the original equation by $4$ to obtain $40x\equiv 12$ so that $x\equiv 12$

Comment: How did you get $x \equiv 12$ from $40 x \equiv 12$?

Comment: $40\equiv 1\mod 13$.

Answer (score 2):

As $(10,13)=1$ using Fermat's Little Theorem, $10^{12}\equiv1\pmod{13}$

$$\implies10^{-1}\equiv10^{11}$$

Again $10\equiv-3,10^{11}\equiv(-3)^{11}\equiv-3^{11}$

and $3^3=27\equiv1\implies3^9\equiv1^3\equiv1$

$\implies-3^{11}\equiv-3^2\equiv-9\equiv4$

Comment: I don't understand. Is my approach wrong, then?>

Comment: @user160292, no, your approach is correct, and so is the above answer: you both got the same, though the above may be a little confusing if you followed your approach.

Comment: @user160292, I think yours is trial & error.  Checking the same for larger modulo can prohibitively complex

Comment: Does my approach work in general? e.g. say I wanted to find $a/b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, could I just solve $a/b \equiv x mod p$ and then $bx \equiv a mod p,$ write out all the possible values of $a mod p,$ and then write $x$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The above seems rather unclear, since the answer doesn't appear to appear in the answer

Comment: @Alan, I think one should be able to reach at the answer if one understands the method. Spoon feeding may not be recommended

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Is the answer 4 or 12, then? The answers seem to contradict each other.

Comment: @user160292, $$10^{-1}\equiv10^{11}\equiv-3^{11}\equiv4$$ $$\implies3\cdot10^{-1}\equiv3\cdot4\pmod{13}$$

Answer (score 2):

This does work, but it's a little awkward to introduce decimals here.

Instead, note that since $$10 \cdot 4 = 40 \equiv 1 \bmod 13,$$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ we have $10^{-1} = 4$ and thus $$3 \cdot (10^{-1}) = 3 \cdot 4 = 12.$$

Comment: Is the line before the decimal part ok? i.e. is it ok to write $$10x \in\{16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34,37, 40,\}$$ and then solve for $x$?

Comment: Yes, though for completeness, since you're apparently working in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ at that point, you should also include $13, 10, 7, \ldots$.

Comment: Ok, but now I get two different answers: 4 and 12. Which one is correct? Wolfram tells me that the solution to $10x \equiv 3 mod 13$ is $x=12$, but I've worked out $x=4.$ Help!

Comment: We have $10^{-1} = 4$, but $3 \cdot 10^{-1} = 12$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $10\equiv -3 \mod 13$, we have that $\dfrac{3}{10}\equiv\dfrac{3}{-3}=-1\equiv 12\mod 13$.